# Access to only one OpenShift application?

Tags: deployment, openshift

The simplest OpenShift account offers up to three applications.

How would I give access to a third party, restricted to only application? They need to be able to deploy code to only that one app.

- I could create a second set of SSH keys - but it seems that keys are account level access: i.e. all applications on that account.
- I could create an Authorization token - but that's also at account level.
- I could just share the SSH details of the application - but then when I want to close access, how would I change the details?

Feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh keys are the way to go.  The third party can provide you their public key so you can add them to your account.  Then, you can give them the UUID and App URL (or git url) for just that one app.  They do potentially have access to all gears within your account, but realistically, its safe to assume they can't guess the UUID of your other apps.

To revoke access, just delete the public key from your account.

Comment: Of course! Never occurred to me to ask them to provide a SSH key. Thanks.